# Selenium WebDriver Wait for javascript generated Table being loaded/visible

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, html-table, webdriverwait

I'm trying to scrape the data within the table of this F5 Article (https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K15386).
The problem I'm facing is that it sometimes crawls the page correctly (tables are within the DOM). Other times however it does not crawl the javascript generated tables.
I have tried using implicit and explicit waits, but with no success. Using explicit wait I am not able to successfully select the table. I am always getting the timeouts.

Any idea on how to always access the data within the tables?
I'm using Java 8, Selenium 3.141.59 & ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
WebElement element = wait
    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("table")));
```

Edit:
I wish I could use their API, however since it is not documented, I am not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
List<WebElement> tables = driver.findElements(By.tagName("table"));
if (tables.size() == 0) {
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.tagName("table")));
        tables.addAll(driver.findElements(By.tagName("table")));
    }
    catch (TimeOutException e) {
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but this still does not solve my problem.